# why windows sysprep is failing

Tags: windows, sysprep

I am seeing that windows sysprep process is failing for windows 10 1909 VMs. The VMs are cloned from a parent VM using Vmware cloning technology and then sysprep is invoked on these clones. I can see that sysprep starts correctly --

```
2020-07-16 07:24:37, Info                  SYSPRP ========================================================
2020-07-16 07:24:37, Info                  SYSPRP ===          Beginning of a new sysprep run          ===
2020-07-16 07:24:37, Info                  SYSPRP ========================================================
2020-07-16 07:24:37, Info       [0x0f004d] SYSPRP The time is now 2020-07-16 07:24:37
2020-07-16 07:24:37, Info       [0x0f004e] SYSPRP Initialized SysPrep log at C:\windows\system32\sysprep\Panther
2020-07-16 07:24:37, Info       [0x0f0054] SYSPRP ValidatePrivileges:User has required privileges to sysprep machine
```

However, it fails at this point--

```
2020-07-16 07:24:47, Info                  SYSPRP SPPNP: Started task '\Microsoft\Windows\Plug and Play\Sysprep Generalize Drivers'...
2020-07-16 07:24:47, Info                  SYSPRP SPPNP: Task state changed to TASK_STATE_READY.
2020-07-16 07:24:51, Info                  SYSPRP SPPNP: Task state changed to TASK_STATE_UNKNOWN.
```

As can be seen above, there is no error, the "Sysprep Generalize Drivers" task is started, but the task goes into unknown state, and there is no entry after that in the sysprep logs. Looks like sysprep just got hung. Didnt get any clue in the windows event logs. Any idea on how to debug and address this would be very much appreciated

Comment: Have you cleaned the Windows captured image from all the bloatwares using [thoses scripts](https://github.com/Sycnex/Windows10Debloater)?